# Bootstrap drop-down acts as a block-level element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Dropdown goes to a new line and the dropdown does not collapse. It displays itself as an list. Is there a problem with the Java script.

I am using bootstrap v3.3.4 and jquery v2.1.2. I have placed Jquery script before the bootstrap.min.js.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Shaunta's Botique</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial scale=1, user-scalable=" no ">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.2.min.js "
            integrity="sha256-YE7BKn1ea9jirCHPr/EaW5NxmkZZGb52+ZaD2UKodXY="
            crossorigin=" anonymous "></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js "></script>
    <script src="js/tether.min.js "></script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- Top Nav Bar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
        <div class="container ">
            <a class="navbar-brand " href="index.php ">Shaunta's Botuqie</a></div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
                <li class="dropdown ">
                    <a href="# " class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown ">Men <span class="caret "></span></a>
                    <ul class="dopdown-menu " role="menu ">
                        <li><a href=" ">Shirts</a></li>
                        <li><a href=" ">Pants</a></li>
                        <li><a href=" ">Shoes</a></li>
                        <li><a href=" ">Accessories</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header-wrapper ">

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few typos in code. Class should be `dropdown-menu`

```
<ul class="dopdown-menu " role="menu ">
```

Also a few attributes like `aria-expanded` and `aria-labelledby` were missing. I have added those attributes as per reference with bootstrap [documentation](http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.3.4/docs/components/#dropdowns).

So the final markup looks like-

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
    <div class="container ">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php ">Shaunta's Botuqie</a></div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class=" dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
            Men
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu " aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href=" ">Shirts</a></li>
            <li><a href=" ">Pants</a></li>
            <li><a href=" ">Shoes</a></li>
            <li><a href=" ">Accessories</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Please refer this working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f0x06n8u/6/).